Vuforia scripts "disappears" and then app crashes
I was warned by a colleague that Vuforia was prone to all sorts of weird errors, but this time it actually drove me crazy.
My project was working perfectly until yesterday. I tried to add an script to enforce autofocus, following a video tutorial by Vuforia developers themselves. Probably it is unrelated to subsequent problems, but I mention it just in case.
Soon I noticed errors: all my image targets stopped working and had a problem with the DefaultObserverEventHandler component. Unity says the script is missing, yet when I created an ImageTarget object, the script was there.
Ran the app, the component went missing. After removing my image targets and creating all of them again, the component seemed to stay there and work, but... when built, the app crashes in the phone as soon as I open the scene with image targets and AR Camera.
The project works perfectly in Unity, using a webcam, but crashes on Android. No significant changes were made. What can be happening here?

Have a look at this troubleshooting guide. https://developer.vuforia.com/library/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-your-app . It might help if you inspect the Android logcat for usefully messages
